# libmosquitto and bcm2835 library for implementing IOT

Tags: iot, libmosquitto

I am working with an IOT based project on raspberry Pi. My project consists of temperature/humidity sensor with zigbee transmitter module(Adam 2017) and a raspbee zigbee receiver, used for reception. The raspbee is interfaced serially with Pi and Pi is connected to a mosquitto server which is running on another PC. So this UART value can be accessed by web UI remotely and based on the temperature and humidity values I want to automatically control a relay. As I had more experience in microcontroller C programming, I select the libmosquitto C client library, mosquitto server and bcm2835 library for this project. I had successfully worked with bcm2835 library in Pi using Geany compiler. But the problem is how I can combine this libmosquitto and bcm2835 library. I had tried by adding the header files and also giving the paths but can't succeed. My aim is to connect the Pi and transfer the UART data to a mosquitto server running on another PC which can be then accessed by web UI. I can't find  any similar projects using libmosquitto and bcm library available on internet?. Can somebody suggest solution for this?

Regards,

Nithin

Comment: Please try to format your question a little as well as provide what you have done so far... maybe some code. Some compiler call etc.

Comment: Yep - what frlan said - is your error in compiling up these sources in to your project, or do you have an error when running them? What you are trying to do is pretty straight forward, so please provide some more details on the specific error and you'll have a better chance at getting an answer.